# JavaScript/jQuery loading bar while page loads?

Tags: javascript

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHynz.png

How does YouTube do this?  I'm assuming it's in JavaScript, how could I add this feature/functionality to my projects so that visitors and/or users know it's loading the content and how much longer it will take?

If you don't understand what's happening from the picture, what it does is loads a red bar across the top as the content of a new page is loading and progresses and disappears when it has finished.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how YoutTube does this but I would expect some inline javascript in the `<head>` would allow you to display something and when the document complete event is fired you could hide it.  Also, HTML streaming could make this work better, I would think, as it could get your JS to the browser ahead of the rest of the document.  Just some thoughts.

Comment: You can use snippet mentioned on http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/display-loading-graphic-until-page-fully-loaded/

Comment: Sublime Package Control (https://sublime.wbond.net/) does this too, and you can find the sources all on GitHub: https://github.com/wbond/sublime.wbond.net. Specifically see the overview for an explanation of how loading is done. I'd assume YouTube does it a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like to just bounce people to a library for an answer, but I found a [really neat jQuery Plugin](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/youtube_loadingbar_demo.html) that does exactly what you want. Pure JavaScript (well, minus the jQuery dependence), but you could reverse-engineer a pure version if you really wanted to.

Hope that helps!